# Scrollview not shwoing images

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

i have retrived images from document directory and want to display that images in scrollview. the images is coming from the document directory but not displaying in scrollview. i have the below code. I have put scrollview graipically on xib and also creat outlet..

```
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 136);
self.scrollView.delegate = self;
int X=0;
for (int i = 0; i < [imageFileNames count]; i++)
{
    NSString *getImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString     stringWithFormat:@"%d/%d.png",b, i]];
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:getImagePath];
    [images addObject:img];
    NSLog(@"%@",getImagePath);
    //imge.image=img;

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(X, 0, 100, 100)] ;
    [imageView setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png", i]]];
    [self.scrollView addSubview: imageView];
    X = X + imageView.frame.size.height+5;

    if(X > 320)
        self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(X, 140);
}
```

Comment: check with background color ,is there images are added or not in scrollview.

Comment: i do not understand you,,sir

Comment: set background color to imageview ,and check weather the images are added to scroll view or not,if added then the problem is in getting image from documentsDirectory and displaying.

Comment: once check @Lirik's answer it'l helps u...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you are trying to create the UIImageView from images that are located in your resources (but they are not there!).

```
[imageView setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png", i]]];
```

whats the point of placing the images in a array, if you dont use it?

try this instead:

```
[imageView setImage: [images objectAtIndex:i]];
```

Comment: You need to make sure images are actually returning from the documents directory. 
I suggest you place 1 image in another UIImageView somewhere and see if the image actually displays.

Comment: yes i have seperate imageview and one image is display here as you can see in my code..imge.image=img; which is commented.

Comment: Ok, i believe that leaves the scrollView.
Since we dont know when exactly this code is called, the scrollview may be nil at this point. check it's not nil, and make sure it's frame is big enough.

Comment: oh, and also the images mutableArray, check it's not nil as well

Comment: well, the next thing i would advise you to try is to create a UIScrollView just before this loop, and try placing it and the images on screen. if it shows, the problem is with the outlet you created